# Resize vmss in azure using azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-vm-scale-set

I want to update size of vmss from Standard_F16s_v2 to Standard_F32s_v2 I usually do it from Ui

[image]

but for some requirement I have to do it from a script so I tried to follow the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss?view=azure-cli-latest

and tried to run this command

```
az vmss update --name MyScaleSet --resource-group MyResourceGroup --vm-sku Standard_F32s_v2
```

but it is not working shows error UnrecognizedArgumentError: unrecognized arguments: --vm-sku Standard_F32s_v2

Comment: hello @KomalNagada, the command seems to be working fine in my environment . May i know what it the az cli version you are using ? I am using `2.30.0` version.

Comment: Thank you for the information after upgrading the cli version I was successfully able to run the command please write this comment as answer and I will mark as solved.

Comment: Sure .. @Komal Nagada

Comment: Glad to be of help @KomalNagada :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with a previous version of `az CLI`  which was resolved by upgrading it to version `2.30.0`.

**Test Scenario :**

[image]

[image]